# recommendation vs recommendation-engine

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) tag has a similar description as [recommendation-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine). Some questions use both tags, where others use either one of them.

[recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) by itself (not in the sense of 'recommendation-engine') is not a good tag, as 'recommendation questions' are (should be) closed as *off-topic*.

Therefore, I propose to make [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) a synonym of [recommendation-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine), or to get rid of it completely.

Comment: I'll update the [tag:recommendation-engine] description using some of the text of [tag:recommendation] as the text is nicer IMO.

Comment: I would challenge the need of either.